# Automated robocopy using variables from a SQL table?

Tags: sql, powershell, md5, robocopy

I'm trying to script (ideally with powershell) a robocopy process that will pull its job values from an SQL table.

For instance on run, it would need to reference the SQL table for the values to construct a command line.

ID then want the log file to be feedback into the tables to update the information (timestamps, file sizes, etc.).

Anyone able to point me in the direction of some good ideas or have any thoughts on this.

Thanks.

Comment: The robocopy tag talks about file and directory copying.  You appear to want to do something else altogether.

Comment: the general idea would be: connect to SQL server via powershell, read the stuff you need, create your robocopy command with a specified log file. Start the process from your powershell script, wait for it to end and then read the log file and update the tables. A lot of tasks, but none of them is overly complicated google will help you with the details for all of them. Parsing the log file may be the most complicated part, but even that depends on the exact requirements.

Comment: Thanks, The robocopy tag is because the process is needed to robocopy from a to b and verify the files afterwards using md5deep. I need to somehow populate tables with the md5deep results, copy the files, and then create robocopy jobs that will copy, and then do a hash check giving us the results.

Comment: I built a tool that does table driven template expansion.  I got the driver table out of a csv file, rather than a database.  But it's the same concept.  It works more or less like mass merge does with a form letter and a mailing list.  Then, all you need is a template that shows a call to robocopy with formal variables for the source and destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I will do

**1). Get Info from Table**

```
Import-Module SQLPS
$dbServer = 'SQLServerName'
$database = 'DBName'

$sourceQuery = "SELECT source from Table" 
$source = Invoke-Sqlcmd -serverinstance $dbServer -Database $database -Query $sourceQuery
```

**2). Run Commands, loop over returned $source/$target array. Ideally wrap it in a function**

```
foreach($sourcePath in $source){robocopy, MD5deep}
```

**3). Capture Outputs and store in variables and then use Stored Procedures if it's easier to update the table with the logs of the above executions.**

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=$($databaseServer);Database=$($database);Integrated Security=True")
$conn.Open() | out-null

$cmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.usp_RobocopyLog", $conn)
$cmd.CommandType = [System.Data.CommandType]'StoredProcedure'

$parameters = @{"ID"=$ID;"Log"=$Output.ToString();}
#Add Parameters if getting from a loop above

    foreach($parameterKey in $parameters.Keys)
    {
        [Void] $cmd.Parameters.Add("@$($parameterKey)",$parameters[$parameterKey])
    }

# Run SQL procedure

$cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() | Out-Null

# Clean-Up

$conn.Close()
```

Invoking SPs will help if multiple tables need to be updated and if there are complex relationships. I can provide more specifics if required